# TSQL for XML CROSS apply to all nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Is it possible to beat that requirments for XML saying `set of nodes is required for 'nodes()'`. In MY example I'm trying to get all values in Data section but list of /Submission/Measures/* is not stable so I'd like to add dynamics to it if it's possible.
Solution below is working with hard coded list in CROSS APPLY, I'm trying to get all node info without specifying the list.

Thanks all and Mr.Khabinsky especially who helped me with first part.

My setup:  Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU22)

Desired output:

[image]

And runnable code, refer to <== tag for needed change

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<Submission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Measures>
        <A100 versionID="A01">
            <Metadata>
                <TY_Year>2020</TY_Year>
                <Benefit>true</Benefit>
            </Metadata>
            <A100_Description>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>11-14</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>13071</RegTotal>
                    <CountA>542</CountA>
                </Data>
            </A100_Description>
            <A100_Description>    <Stratification>     <Pool>4-6</Pool>         </Stratification>
                <Data>   <RegTotal>8995</RegTotal>     <CountA>366</CountA>     </Data>
            </A100_Description>
            <A100_Description>   <Stratification>     <Pool>7-10</Pool>         </Stratification>
                <Data>   <RegTotal>11818</RegTotal>   <CountA>546</CountA>      </Data>
            </A100_Description>
        </A100>
        <B200 versionID="B12">
            <Metadata>
                <TY_Year>2020</TY_Year>
                <Benefit>true</Benefit>
            </Metadata>
            <B200_Description>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>12-18</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>349</RegTotal>
                    <X5>12</X5>
                    <CountA>269</CountA>
                    <CountB>0</CountB>
                </Data>
            </B200_Description>
        </B200>

      <z300 versionID="B33">
            <z300_Descr>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>19-50</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>33333</RegTotal>
                    <X5>3333</X5>
                    <CountA>333</CountA>
                    <CountB>33</CountB>
                </Data>
            </z300_Descr>
      </z300>
    </Measures>
</Submission>';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT r.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [Msr]  
    , c.value('(Stratification/Pool/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [Pool]
    , c.value('(Data/RegTotal/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [RegTotal]
    , c.value('(Data/X5/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [X5]
    , c.value('(Data/CountA/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [CountA]
    , c.value('(Data/CountB/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [CountB]
 FROM @xml.nodes('/Submission/Measures/*') AS p(r)
 CROSS APPLY p.r.nodes('A100_Description, B200_Description, z300_Descr') AS t(c);     --How CROSS Apply to all nodes without listing them (to get all 3) ????
 --  CROSS APPLY p.r.nodes('/Submission/Measures/*') AS t(c);                 --<=== set of nodes is required for 'nodes()'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is using the following:

- XML wildcard **'*'**, i.e. asterisk, to handle dynamic XML element names.
- Negative logic to filter out not needed `<Metadata>` XML fragment.
- `OUTER APPLY` simulates `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to preserve parent data
  set for a scenario without children.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<Submission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Measures>
        <A100 versionID="A01">
            <Metadata>
                <TY_Year>2020</TY_Year>
                <Benefit>true</Benefit>
            </Metadata>
            <A100_Description>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>11-14</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>13071</RegTotal>
                    <CountA>542</CountA>
                </Data>
            </A100_Description>
            <A100_Description>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>4-6</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>8995</RegTotal>
                    <CountA>366</CountA>
                </Data>
            </A100_Description>
            <A100_Description>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>7-10</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>11818</RegTotal>
                    <CountA>546</CountA>
                </Data>
            </A100_Description>
        </A100>
        <B200 versionID="B12">
            <Metadata>
                <TY_Year>2020</TY_Year>
                <Benefit>true</Benefit>
            </Metadata>
            <B200_Description>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>12-18</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>349</RegTotal>
                    <X5>12</X5>
                    <CountA>269</CountA>
                    <CountB>0</CountB>
                </Data>
            </B200_Description>
        </B200>
        <z300 versionID="B33">
            <z300_Descr>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>19-50</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>33333</RegTotal>
                    <X5>3333</X5>
                    <CountA>333</CountA>
                    <CountB>33</CountB>
                </Data>
            </z300_Descr>
        </z300>
    </Measures>
</Submission>';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT p.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [Msr]  
    , c.value('(Stratification/Pool/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [Pool]
    , c.value('(Data/RegTotal/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [RegTotal]
    , c.value('(Data/X5/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [X5]
    , c.value('(Data/CountA/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [CountA]
    , c.value('(Data/CountB/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [CountB]
FROM @xml.nodes('/Submission/Measures/*') AS t1(p)
    OUTER APPLY t1.p.nodes('*[local-name()!="Metadata"]') AS t2(c);
```

**Output**

```
+------+-------+----------+------+--------+--------+
| Msr  | Pool  | RegTotal |  X5  | CountA | CountB |
+------+-------+----------+------+--------+--------+
| A100 | 11-14 |    13071 | NULL |    542 | NULL   |
| A100 | 4-6   |     8995 | NULL |    366 | NULL   |
| A100 | 7-10  |    11818 | NULL |    546 | NULL   |
| B200 | 12-18 |      349 | 12   |    269 | 0      |
| z300 | 19-50 |    33333 | 3333 |    333 | 33     |
+------+-------+----------+------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: big thanks  Yitzhak again !. Could not think of or found that "Metada" option !!!

Comment: @Mich28, SQL Server XQuery functionality is pretty awesome. Please up-vote my suggestion to make it even more powerful: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali

Comment: XQuery functionality should meet its expert -) like in this case. I will follow you link to vote.Spasibo.V